# Do these sentences gain any difference in meaning by reversing the order?

Tags: grammar, word-order

Is there any difference between those sentences?

> 1. I was there *to get a hair cut yesterday.*
> 2. I was there *yesterday to get a hair cut.*
> 3. Option one is to invest the money so that it will compound annually
>      *for the next ten years at the rate of 4%.*
> 4. Option one is to invest the money so that it will compound annually *at
>      the rate of 4% for the next 10 years.*

Do these sentences gain any difference in meaning by reversing the order?

Comment: In one and two, the difference is between setting the scene before telling a story, and pitching right in, the haircut is part of the narrative; in three and four there are different levels of commitment.

Comment: Can you elaborate the difference between one and two a little more? I don't fully understand the difference.They just seem the same to me.

Comment: @Hugh I believe that if you invested $100 under either 3 or 4, at the end of ten years, you'd have $148.02 no matter which you chose.

Comment: @deadrat Do number one and two seem different to you?

Comment: @sooeithdk They seem identical to me, but why would you go to get one hair cut?

Comment: In the first sentence, "I was there to get a hair cut yesterday", does yesterday modify the whole sentence or only " to get a hair cut" part?

Comment: @deadrat .3. The option is **to invest for ten years** (and the rate is 4% compound).  .4. The proposed option is **to invest;** and whether I leave it invested for one year or seven or seventeen, the rate for ten years will be 4% compound.

Comment: @sooeithdk Does it matter?  See my comment below chasly's answer.

Comment: @Hugh Thanks for the explanation.  At least I can now understand the difference that people are talking about.  I still don't believe it's there, although I hasten to add again that maybe it's just me.  There's one option (well, it's "Option one," I guess), and I think that makes the prepositional phrases as compound as the interest.  That is, the sentence means at 4% *and* for 10 years, making the order immaterial.

Comment: Let's suppose we use the same *gedankenexperiment* as the one I gave below chasly's answer and presente each phrasing of the option to separate groups of 100 people, each with access to a compound interest calculator.  When we ask, "How much money will you end up with?" do you suppose that people who read the phrasing in 3. will say $148.02, and the people who read the phrasing 4. will ask how long the money will remain invested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In writing, placing a word or phrase at the end of a sentence generally gives it greater focus. So in "I was there to get a hair cut yesterday," the focus is on when the subject got his hair cut, whereas in "I was there yesterday to get a hair cut," the focus is on why the subject was there yesterday. Of course, when speaking we tend to use stress and intonation more than word order to show this.

Comment: Thank you for the description. It is very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

The real difference comes when they are in context, e.g.

> Didn't I see you in the shopping centre recently?
>
> Maybe - I was there to get a haircut yesterday.

---

> Have you visited the new shopping centre yet?
>
> I was there yesterday to get a haircut.

**Note**

I'm not saying that it's impossible to swap those over but there really is a difference according to context. The other thing to take note of, and unfortunately it cannot be shown via text, is the different intonation that goes with the sentences.

Comment: Oh...so the first one emphasizes the time but the second one emphasizes the purpose?

Comment: I have just experimented with different tonalities. I can say the first sentence in at least four different ways without any difficulty and the nuances are different. The true distinction is that it's possible to vary both versions tonally but not equally. Unless I start using musical notation I don't know how to express it better :-(

Comment: In the first sentence, "I was there to get a hair cut yesterday", does yesterday modify the whole sentence or only " to get a hair cut" part?

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, since everybody else seems to find the different nuances without trouble.  Suppose you had two groups of 100 people, and you had the first group read the sentence with "yesterday" at the end and the second group read the sentence with "haircut" at the end.  Then you asked all 200, "Where was I, when did I go, and why was I there?" Do you suppose the answers would differ across the two groups?